# How to "observe" a stream in Ruby's CSV module?

Tags: ruby, export-to-csv

I am writing a class that takes a CSV files, transforms it, and then writes the new data out.

```
module Transformer
  class Base
    def initialize(file)
      @file = file
    end

    def original_data(&block)
      opts = { headers: true }
      CSV.open(file, 'rb', opts, &block)
    end

    def transformer
      # complex manipulations here like modifying columns, picking only certain
      # columns to put into new_data, etc but simplified to `+10` to keep
      # example concise
      -> { |row| new_data << row['some_header'] + 10 }
    end

    def transformed_data
      self.original_data(self.transformer) 
    end

    def write_new_data
      CSV.open('new_file.csv', 'wb', opts) do |new_data|
        transformed_data
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What I'd like to be able to do is:

- Look at the transformed data without writing it out (so I can test that it transforms the data correctly, and I don't *need* to write it to file right away: maybe I want to do more manipulation before writing it out)
- Don't slurp all the file at once, so it works no matter the size of the original data
- Have this as a base class with an empty `transformer` so that instances only need to implement their own transformers but the behavior for reading and writing is given by the base class.

But obviously the above doesn't work because I don't really have a reference to `new_data` in `transformer`.

How could I achieve this elegantly?

Comment: What is `constructor`?

Comment: my bad, got mixed up with JS. It should be `initialize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend one of two approaches, depending on your needs and personal taste.

I have intentionally distilled the code to just its bare minimum (without your wrapping class), for clarity.

#### 1. Simple read-modify-write loop

Since you do not want to slurp the file, use `CSV::Foreach`. For example, for a quick debugging session, do:

```
CSV.foreach "source.csv", headers: true do |row|
  row["name"] = row["name"].upcase
  row["new column"] = "new value"
  p row
end
```

And if you wish to write to file during that same iteration:

```
require 'csv'

csv_options = { headers: true }

# Open the target file for writing
CSV.open("target.csv", "wb") do |target|
  # Add a header
  target << %w[new header column names]

  # Iterate over the source CSV rows
  CSV.foreach "source.csv", **csv_options do |row|
    # Mutate and add columns
    row["name"] = row["name"].upcase
    row["new column"] = "new value"

    # Push the new row to the target file
    target << row
  end
end
```

#### 2. Using `CSV::Converters`

There is a built in functionality that might be helpful - `CSV::Converters` - (see the `:converters` definition in the [`CSV::New`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) documentation)

```
require 'csv'

# Register a converter in the options hash
csv_options = { headers: true, converters: [:stripper] }

# Define a converter
CSV::Converters[:stripper] = lambda do |value, field|
  value ? value.to_s.strip : value
end

CSV.open("target.csv", "wb") do |target|
  # same as above

  CSV.foreach "source.csv", **csv_options do |row|
    # same as above - input data will already be converted
    # you can do additional things here if needed
  end
end
```

#### 3. Separate input and output from your converter classes

Based on your comment, and since you want to minimize I/O and iterations, perhaps extracting the read/write operations from the responsibility of the transformers might be of interest. Something like this.

```
require 'csv'

class NameCapitalizer
  def self.call(row)
    row["name"] = row["name"].upcase
  end
end

class EmailRemover
  def self.call(row)
    row.delete 'email'
  end
end

csv_options = { headers: true }
converters = [NameCapitalizer, EmailRemover]

CSV.open("target.csv", "wb") do |target|
  CSV.foreach "source.csv", **csv_options do |row|
    converters.each { |c| c.call row }
    target << row
  end
end
```

Note that the above code still does not handle the header, in case it was changed. You will probably have to reserve the last row (after all transformations) and prepend its `#headers` to the output CSV.

There are probably plenty other ways to do it, but the CSV class in Ruby does not have the cleanest interface, so I try to keep code that deals with it as simple as I can.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that I'd like to have instances only define their own "converter" which would be the block that manipulates/converts/strips data from the original CSV to the format and columns to write in the new CSV file. The only way that I could do that, I think, is with a lambda. But I don't know how to make that lambda have access to both the original CSV object, and the transformed CSV object to write out. Your suggesstion essentially wraps it all into one method, and instances inheriting from it would have to reimplement it all from scratch, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: What I posted was example code of how to eliminate reading / writing the file several times. I added another option, hopefully one of these three will point you in the right direction. What you want to do is definitely possible, but if you want to avoid reading/writing files in the intermediate steps, then your classes should probably not deal with files at all, but only with the data they are responsible for.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something similar, but I didn't use converters because I also needed side effects (increment some counters, etc). I did however create functions that take a `row` and processes it. One of the functions transforms the data, and this one returns an array of fields which I can shovel into target. This gives me a cleaner API, as the base class implements all the logic of opening and writing to files etc, while its children only focus on the transformations. Ideally, I'd have this class return a `CSV::Table` and handle the file IO somewhere else, but alas.